# Macbook Pro connected to HDMI, but no sound?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi

I have a Macbook Pro 13" and it's a mid 2012 model. It's hooked up to my TV through the HDMI cord as well as the mini display adapter and the display is great, but there's no sound at all. My computer recognizes the HDMI cord and that option is selected. It's also selected via the opt button then clicking the sound, as well as through the MIDI application. I have also tried two different HDMI cords with no luck. I've been looking around and absolutely nothing fixes my problem. I'm really confused as to how my computer could recognize all this being connected and still produce no sound. Can anybody help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you using a built-in HDMI port (the MBP Retina models sport these) or are you using a Mini-display <> HDMI adaptor?

Answer (score 1):

You need a mini DisplayPort (mDP) to HDMI adapter with audio support.

One like [BlueRigger](http://amzn.to/1jVSl3M) adapter should work perfectly for your application.
[image: BlueRigger mDP to HDMI with Audio]

If you look at the [Tech Specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US) page from Apple specific to your model, you will see that HDMI video with audio is supported.

Just plug in your HDMI cable to that adapter and the other end into your TV and you are good to go.

[image]